Send email only if attachment exists in import SFTP Marketing Cloud

I have an incoming zip file containing multiple csv files. I extract and run an automation activity on a specific file name pattern, this is the master data file containing which file goes as an attachment to which email address.

once this master data is loaded in Data Extension, I use the Send Email activity to send the email with attachment.


To Do

How do I send an email only if the file to be attached is present in the import folder ? (otherwise the email still sent without attachment)

Can I ?

Is there an AMPScript to skip an activity to be carried out ?
Can I write a SQL activity to verify if a file exists ?


The standard functionality of AttachFile function is to throw an error if a file specified in AttachFile function cannot be found.

NOTE: If the specified file cannot be found at send time, the send
will throw a runtime error and abort.

Source
You might want to contact Salesforce to adjust this error behaviour, as sendtime errors come in two flavours:

Prevents only this specific email from being sent, while continuing the send job
Stop both the current email, while also cancelling the rest of the send job

You obviously want to ensure, the setting is giving you the first option.

You can also contact your account executive to adjust the error
threshold that causes the send job to stop prematurely. This feature
helps prevent a single error from stopping the entire job.

Source

Thank you Lukas.
